# [Nonsense question stemming from a simple typo]

Tags: python, matplotlib, quadratic

**My confusion was just based on a typo in my code - nothing interesting to learn here!**
I simply plotted the wrong function, see my comment to the accepted answer.

Here are some seemingly harmless Python code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
  
delta = 0.02    
    
x = np.arange(-10, 10, delta) 
y = np.arange(-10, 10, delta) 
[X, Y] = np.meshgrid(x, y) 
  
fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
  
Z = X**2+2*X*Y+Y**2
# for comparison later use this:
#Z = 3.14*X**2+0.6*Y**2 
  
ax.contour(X, Y, Z)   
ax.set_xlabel('x') 
ax.set_ylabel('y') 
  
plt.show()
```

and its output:

[image]

The plotted contour lines are wrong! I am doing the contour plot of a quadratic function and the contour lines should be ellipses. The shown lines are not just seemingly lines, which at a bigger scale would become ellipses. I have at least two reasons for saying so:

1. Here is the [Wolfram Alpha contour plot of the same function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2B2xy%2B3y%5E2) at a similar scale. It shows the ellipsis that should be there.
2. I calculated by hand the corresponding diagonal quadratic form (according to the [Principal Axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_axis_theorem)): It is, with a bit of rounding, `Z = 3.14*X**2+0.6*Y**2`.

This a function which first rotates a given vector `(X,Y)` by a certain angle and then applies the function `Z = X**2+2*X*Y+Y**2` used in the code. Thus the contour plots of the two functions should just differ by a rotation.

But inserting `Z = 3.14*X**2+0.6*Y**2` in the above code, in place of the previous `Z`, produces a perfectly fine ellipsis:

[image]

My questions:

1. What is the explanation for his behaviour?
2. What can I do to get an accurate contour plot of the first function?

Comment: please add the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matplotlib contour plot is correct.

A) We can look at the 3D projection:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

delta = 2  
    
x = np.arange(-100, 100, delta) 
y = np.arange(-100, 100, delta) 
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)   
  
Z = X**2 + Y**2 + 2*X*Y
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)

plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]

Yup, lines parallel to `x = -y`.

B) Let's look at the mathematical representation for `x+y=a`, i.e., `y=a-x`

Then it follows:
z = x² + y² + 2xy
= x² + (a-x)² + 2x(a-x)
= x² + a² - 2ax + x² + 2ax - 2x²
= a²

And this is what we see in the surface plot, as well as in the contour plot - for lines parallel to `x=-y`, the `z`-value is independent of `x` (or `y`) and just depends on `a` (and is symmetrical for positive and negative `a`-values).

C) Obviously, the contour plots differ for `a` in `x²+2xy+ay²` (as you expected). But because we can, let's add this little example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
  
delta = 0.02  
    
x = np.arange(-10, 10, delta) 
y = np.arange(-10, 10, delta) 
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y) 
  
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 3, figsize=(10,10)) 
  
Z = X**2 + Y**2 + 3*Y*X
# for comparison later use this:
#Z = 3.14*X**2+0.6*Y**2 

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    a=i-2
    Z = X**2 + a* Y**2 + 2*X*Y
    cs = ax.contour(X, Y, Z)
    ax.clabel(cs, inline=True, fontsize=10)
    ax.set_title("x²+2xy+ay² for a="+str(a))
  
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: Oh no, I just had a typo in my function! I meant to look at x^2+3y^2+2xy. That's the function whose contour I wanted to see, and whose diagonal form I had calculated. Problem solved, thanks!

Comment: Or is that considered bad behaviour on this site? I don't know...

Comment: Sorry, da real life interfered and I had to leave in the middle of my answer. I wanted to add that `x²+2xy+ay²` looks different for any other `a` apart from 1 and that the Wolfram formula differs but you have found out about it yourself, so all is good. And because I can, I added some more code. I think this question taught me something

Comment: Great pictures, thanks! On top of finding my typo, I learned some plotting from you!